# Magento2 - How to customization of the invoice pdf deign using php not using phtml

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php

example for this

```
 // Add "INVOICE" text above the barcode
 $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
 $page->setFont($font, 26);
 $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0)); // Black color
 $page->drawText('INVOICE', $docHeader[2] - $width - $padding_right, $docHeader[1] - $padding_top - (-3)); // Adjust position with padding -10
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the PDF invoice in Magento 2, you'll need to override the Invoice.php file. You can refer to the following link for detailed instructions on how to override this:

https://www.mageants.com/blog/how-to-create-and-customize-invoice-pdf-in-magento-2-programmatically.html

Then After you can add customization as per your requirement below some zend pdf Framework properties

**1.Page Creation and Manipulation:**

- **newPage($pageSize):** Creates a new page with the specified size.
- **pages[]:** Array containing all the pages of the PDF document.
- **drawText($text, $x, $y):** Draws text at the specified coordinates on the page.
- **drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2):** Draws an image onto the page with specified coordinates.

**2.Fonts and Text:**

- **setFont($font, $fontSize):** Sets the font and font size for drawing text.
- **setFont(Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font $font, $fontSize):** Sets the font and font size for drawing text.
- **Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName($fontName):** Retrieves a font object by name.

**3.Colors:**

- **setFillColor($color):** Sets the fill color for subsequent drawing operations.
- **setLineColor($color):** Sets the line color for subsequent drawing operations.
- **Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb:** Class representing RGB colors.
- **Zend_Pdf_Color_Cmyk:** Class representing CMYK colors.
- **Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale:** Class representing grayscale colors.

**4.Drawing Shapes:**

- **drawRectangle($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2):** Draws a rectangle on the page.
- **drawLine($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2):** Draws a line between two points.
- **drawPolygon(array $points, $fillType):** Draws a polygon using an array of points.

**5.Document Metadata:**

- **properties[]:** Array containing the metadata properties of the PDF document.
- **properties['Title']:** Title of the PDF document.
- **properties['Author']:** Author of the PDF document.
- **properties['Subject']:** Subject of the PDF document.
- **properties['Keywords']:** Keywords associated with the PDF document.

**6.Encryption and Security:**

- **setEncryption($userPassword, $ownerPassword, $encryptionType):** Sets encryption for the PDF document.
- **setPermissions($permissions):** Sets permissions for the encrypted PDF document.

**7.Document Information:**

- **getPages():** Retrieves all the pages in the PDF document.
- **save($filename, $updateOnly = false):** Saves the PDF document to a file.
- **render():** Returns the PDF document as a string.

**8.Images:**

- **Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imagePath):** Creates an image object from the specified image file.

For more details you can refer below reference link

https://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3.1/modules/zendpdf.drawing.html
https://www.aspirationhosting.com/magento-2-custom-pdf/